# How to check max sum value in a map

Tags: map

I have a map which returns value in debug like below -

```
{"name":"Cleaning","sum":2}
{"name":"Treatment","sum":1}
```

I want to check the max or greater of sum which is **2** for the above case and print the name which is **cleaning**

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple programming:

```
Integer max = -1; // (I'm assuming all >= 0)
String maxName = '';

for(String key: theMap.keySet())
{
  if(theMap.get(key) > max)
  {
    maxName = key;
    max = theMap.get(key);
  }
}

console.log(maxName);
```

Note, if several values are the same it'll use the first. Now, normally I'd have closed this as being off topic but I answered because you should consider why you're doing this. If the data is from the system there's better ways of getting the max value, such as using an aggregate SOQL query. If this is for Trailhead or something then it will be closed as off topic ;)